# Allocating memory using new returns same memory address

Tags: c++

```
class abc  {
    int x ;
};
int main()
{
    abc *A = new abc ;
    cout<< static_cast<void*>(A) << endl ;
    delete A ;
    cout<< static_cast<void*>(A) << endl ;
    abc *B = new abc ;
    cout<< static_cast<void*>(B) << endl ;
    delete B ;
    cout<< static_cast<void*>(B) << endl ;



    return 0;

}
```

Why it prints the same address , even though i deleted old memory .
Even i assign null after deletion , it prints the same address.

Even address of A and B is same .

**Real time scenario :**

```
Function1 ->   
arr[p] = new X  
ptr1 = arr[p]  
using ptr1 

Function2 ->   
ptr2 = arr[p]  
delete ptr2  
arr[p] = new X ( new data)
```

In real scenario ptr1 should be invalidated but since compiler assign same address to
arr[p] in function2 ptr1 still works .

Comment: Could you provide output ?

Comment: 0x11d5a010  0x11d5a010
0x11d5a010
0x11d5a010

Comment: "Even i assign null after deletion" - huh? doesn't matter.

Comment: "Even address of A and B is same" that's just a coincidence. ( probably you have only one block of heap memory...just joking).

Comment: Nothing in particular happens to pointers when memory they point to is freed - it's the programmers responsibility not to use an invalid pointer. That it "still works" is a special form of undefined behaviour.

Comment: "ptr1 should be invalidated" - I don't think you understand what "invalidated" means. It means you can't use it any more (without causing undefined behaviour). It doesn't mean it goes into a special state which stops you from using it. It will retain its previous address, which might or might not be used for some other object at some other time.

Answer (score 7):

Why should this not happen? Once you've deleted memory at a particular address, the memory manager is perfectly at liberty to re-use that address the next time you ask for new memory. Indeed this is a very common optimisation used by memory managers. They keep track of recently freed blocks and hand them back to the next client that requests a block of that size.

Another way to look at this would be to consider what would happen if freed addresses were never re-used. If that were to happen then eventually, after enough allocation/deallocation cycles, there would be no address space left. Indeed, if re-use never happened then there would be no point at all in deallocating memory. So yes, do expect that when you deallocate memory, that memory address will be re-used.

Comment: Address of A and B is coming same .

Comment: Yes I know. That's what you said in the question isn't it. My answer explained why,

Comment: @AvinashKumar You're printing the address *stored in* `A` and and `B`, not the address *of* `A` and `B`. Since you've called `delete` on the old block, the allocator can easily reuse it.

Comment: I answered the question that you asked. If you want to ask a new one, feel free to do so. First of all can we get on top of the question that you asked. Do you understand the behaviour yet.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i understood your previous explanation  , please tell what to do in my given scenario.

Comment: That's not how it works around here. I don't fully understand your new question yet. What you should do is as follows: 1. Revert the question to its original form. Then the answers will all make sense because they address the question you asked. 2. Accept the answer your judge to be best. 3. Ask a new question about your new problem.

Answer (score 3):

it is because you are deleting the pointers.do not delete them you will see the difference.

```
abc *A = new abc ;
abc *B = new abc ;
```

Comment: this is not my question , i know this

Answer (score 2):

```
abc *A = new abc ;
```

This will allocate enough memory to hold abc object and make A point to that address( Let's say address is 0x1234). So, A contains value 0x1234.

delete A;

will deallocate that memory( that means memory is returned to free store). But A still contains the value of that memory address i.e 0x1234.

Deleting same pointer two times makes for undefined behavior is a conseqeunce of this thing only as second time you would be deleting the memory which is not yours.

That's why you do

```
A= NULL;
```

after deleting the memory.

Comment: Yes I know that I have just explained something extra related to your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Memory you freed is not used anymore. Memory manager can use the heap as it wants - allocating next free space - the one you actually freed just before.

Answer (score 0):

```
abc *A = new abc ;
cout<< static_cast<void*>(A) << endl ;
```

This is the first output.

```
delete A ;
cout<< static_cast<void*>(A) << endl ;
```

Though it is after `delete` the value of `A` remains the same. What `delete` did was: 1. call the destructor (in this case trivial) of `A` and 2. Inform the memory allocator that the memory allocated for `A` is now free and can be used for other purposes.

```
abc *B = new abc ;
cout<< static_cast<void*>(B) << endl ;
```

It may be that in this step output will be still the same - since allocator has the memory previously allocated for `A` for use now, it may use it for `B`.

```
delete B ;
cout<< static_cast<void*>(B) << endl ;
```

The same as before with `A`.